# PHP IF Statement how can I write it more elegant and effective

Tags: php

I now have this code based on some of the answers below.

Is this the most elegant, clean, fast and effective code to have?

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying Google Analytics
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage News_Template
 * @since News Template 1.0
 */
$googleanalyticscode="<script type='text/javascript'> var _gaq = _gaq || []; _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '%s']); _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '%s']);   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })(); </script>";
$analyticsurlgoogle=array(
    'domain-a.com' => 'UA-25133-2',
    'domain-b.com' => 'UA-25133',
    'domain-c.com' => 'UA-2699-2',
    'domain-d.com' => 'UA-3021-2',
    'domain-e.com' => 'UA-25537-2',
    'domain-f.com' => 'UA-7213-2',
    'domain-g.com' => 'UA-7214-2',
    'domain-h.com' => 'UA-150-2',
    'domain-i.com' => 'UA-150-2'
); 
// --- /Configuration --- 
// Get the Domain URL 
$analyticsurl = get_site_url(); 
$namegoogle = substr($analyticsurl,7); 
//create code 
if (isset($analyticsurlgoogle[$namegoogle])) $code=sprintf($googleanalyticscode,$analyticsurlgoogle[$namegoogle],$namegoogle); 
else $code=''; 
echo $code; ?>
```

------ Previous Code ------

I have written the following if statement in PHP. What would be the most elegant, effective and cleanest way of writing this code?

The purpose of the code is to check the domain name of the site. If the site have google analytics defined it should match the defined "Google Analytics" code for the domain and then print the script to the page.

If the Google Analytics code is not defined it should show nothing!

```
<?php 
// Get the Domain URL
$analyticsurl = get_site_url();
// Check if domain is defined
if ($analyticsurl == 'http://domain-a.com') {$analyticcode = 'UA-25133920-1'; $analyticsurlname = 'domain-a.com';} // domain-a.com
if ($analyticsurl == 'http://domain-b.com') {$analyticcode = 'UA-25133920-1'; $analyticsurlname = 'domain-b.com';} // domain-b.com
if ($analyticsurl == 'http://domain-c.com') {$analyticcode = 'UA-26990264-1'; $analyticsurlname = 'domain-c.com';} // domain-c.com
if ($analyticsurl == 'http://domain-d.com') {$analyticcode = 'UA-30217571-1'; $analyticsurlname = 'domain-d.com';} // domain-d.com
if ($analyticsurl == 'http://domain-e.com') {$analyticcode = 'UA-25537388-1'; $analyticsurlname = 'domain-e.com';} // domain-e.com
// if domain is defined create Google Analytics Code and insert variables
$analyticscode_1 = "<script type='text/javascript'>
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '".$analyticcode."']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '".$analyticsurlname."']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>";
// if URL does not match write nothing
if ($analyticcode == '') {$analyticscode = '';}
// if URL exists set the Google Analytics Code
if ($analyticcode != '') {$analyticscode = $analyticscode_1;}
?>
<?php // write the Analytics code to the page
echo $analyticscode ?>
```

Comment: Better to use switch/case instead of so many `if` on same variable. Also even your `ifs` should have been `if/elseif/elseif/else` to be slightly more efficient.

Comment: How dynamic is this list of domain names?  Are you adding values to the list frequently?  Perhaps the fact that this code smells to you is a good indication that you need to use a different storage medium here, such as a database.

Comment: @Chris i would like to know the reason too of all his/her downvotes

Comment: My sites receives alot of hits and I want to try to save requests to the db...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

// --- Configuration ---

$template="<script type ... 
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '%s']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '%s']);
  ...
</script>";

$urls=array(
 'domain-a.com' => 'UA-25133920-1',
 ...
 'domain-e.com' => 'UA-25537388-1'
);

// --- /Configuration ---

// Get the Domain URL
$url = get_site_url();
$name = substr($analyticsurl,7);

//create code
if (isset($urls[$name])) $code=sprintf($template,$urls[$name],$name);
else $code='';

// ...

echo $code;
?>
```

Comment: I am looking at this code at the moment. This solution works best for me at the moment. I had to change the variables as it were clashing with other variables. Once I made the variables unique it looks like the best solution

Answer (score 4):

Parse the url with parse_url (or remove the http:// part with a regexp).

Put all the codes in an array, where key is the domain name. Then it's a simple lookup.

```
$codes = array(
 'domain-a.com' => 'UA-25133920-1',
  //...
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me got to the answer

Answer (score 1):

A [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) statement.

Comment: The reference helped - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i would hold all the records in a single array so that i don't repeat the condition again and again.

```
$siteurl = get_site_url();

$analyticsurl = array(
    'http://domain-a.com' => 'UA-25133920-1', 
    'http://domain-b.com' => 'UA-25133920-1', 
    'http://domain-c.com' => 'UA-26990264-1', 
    'http://domain-d.com' => 'UA-30217571-1', 
    'http://domain-e.com' => 'UA-25537388-1'
);

if(in_array($siteurl, $analyticsurl)) {
    $analyticcode = $analyticsurl[$siteurl];
    $analyticsurlname = str_replace('http://', '', $siteurl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a switch statement:

```
switch ($analyticsurl)
{
 case: 'http://domain-a.com':
 // do some stuff
 break;

 case: 'http://domain-b.com':
 // do some stuff
 break;

 case: 'http://domain-c.com':
 // do some stuff
 break;

 case: 'http://domain-d.com':
 // do some stuff
 break;

 case 'http://domain-e.com':
 // do some stuff
 break;

 default:
 // do something by default if no match
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$domains['http://domain-a.com']['code'] = 'UA-25133920-1';
$domains['http://domain-a.com']['urlname'] = 'domain-a.com';
$domains['http://domain-b.com']['code'] = 'UA-25133920-1';
$domains['http://domain-b.com']['urlname'] = 'domain-b.com';
...

// Get the Domain URL
$analyticsurl = get_site_url();

// Check if domain is defined
if (array_key_exists($analyticsurl)) {
    // if domain is defined create Google Analytics Code and insert variables
?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<?php= $domains[$analyticsurl]['code'] ?>']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '<?php= $domains[$analyticsurl]['urlname'] ?>']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

`$domains['http://domain-b.com']['urlname'] = 'domain-b.com';` could be improved, because your just stripping the HTTP-part, but I was too lazy to provide a solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

Use a switch block:

```
switch ($analyticsurl) {
    case: 'http://domain-a.com' :
        $analyticcode = 'UA-25133920-1';
        $analyticsurlname = 'domain-a.com';
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```